# Laravel 8 and Sanctum - Postman login thru /api/login

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum

I have configured a Postman environment and everything seems to work except that I can't login with Postman on `http://localhost:8000/api/login`.

Accessing the api/login endpoint returns `"message": "User login successfully"` and creates the appropriate cookies, but all the other endpoints show `"message": "Unauthenticated."`.

Everything works when I login thru `http://localhost:8000/login` but that's not something I'd like to do because this requires `Auth::routes();` in `web.php` which I'm not going to use since I'm creating a SPA.

Logging in thru `api/login` works just fine with Vue and Axios, and I wonder, why doesn't it work with Postman?

Pre-request Script:

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    method: 'GET'
}, function (error, response, { cookies }) {
    if (!error) {
        pm.environment.set('xsrf-token', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you add Authorization header with token in postman?

Comment: Totally missed that one. Thanks!